# Unable to retrieve the Data from web service to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was Unable to retrieve the data from web service and display the same in my UITableView cell. I was able to see the data that was added in the past. When I go to my application, add a record I was not able to see any thing. Here is the below code. To make sure I was using IOS 8, Xcode 6. I worked on this application in the recent past and use to work fine in IOS 7 or IOS 6. When I upgraded there are few problems like not displaying the data in UITabelView

```
-(void)loadprojects
{

    NSString *eventDate = self.StringfromTextField3;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:eventDate forKey:@"Eventdate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@",[self.tableView dataSource]];
    NSString *strwebsite = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"website"];
    NSString *websitemethods = @"Timesheet.svc/GetTimesheet";
    NSString *projecturltemp = [strwebsite stringByAppendingString:websitemethods];
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
    NSString *usrid = str;
    NSString * projecturl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",projecturltemp,usrid,eventDate];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:projecturl];

    //NSLog(@"url : %@", url);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];




    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];


    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];
    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
        if(!entries)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
        }
        else{

            for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
                projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
                taskNames = [entries valueForKey:@"TASk_NAME"];
                subtaskNames = [entries valueForKey:@"SUBTASK_NAME"];
                timesheetid = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_TIMESHEET_DTLS"];
                projId = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_PROJECT"];
                taskId = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_TASK"];
                subtaskId = [entries valueForKey:@"ID_SUB_TASK"];
                totalhours = [entries valueForKey:@"No_Hours"];
                approve = [entries valueForKey:@"FL_APPROVE"];
                leaves = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_LEAVE"];
            }
        }

    }       else {

    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [projectNames count];

}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identitifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identitifier
                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[[timesheetid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.lblProjects.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Projects Filled"];
        cell.lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Tasks Filled"];
        cell.lblSubTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No SubTasks Filled"];
        cell.lblHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"0 Hours Filled"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else if ([[leaves objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.lblProjects.text = [projectNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblHours.text = [[totalhours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"cell :%@",cell.lblHours.text);
        NSLog(@"lblProjects :%@",cell.lblProjects.text);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblProjects.text = [leaves objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Projects/Tasks on this Date"];
        cell.lblSubTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Sub Tasks on this Date"];
        cell.lblHours.text = [[totalhours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    }
    cell.editingAccessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    NSNumber *myProjectArrayString = [timesheetid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.hdbrowcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myProjectArrayString];

    return cell;


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"index :%@",[timesheetid objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:indexPath];
    //[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueNameforAddPage"])
    {
        UINavigationController *segueNameNavController=segue.destinationViewController;
        AddProjectDetails *NavWeekScreen = (AddProjectDetails*)segueNameNavController.topViewController;

        NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserLoginIdSession"];
        NavWeekScreen.projidstocancel = self.StringfromTextField3;
        NavWeekScreen.StringfromProjectsTasksscreenuser=str;
        NSInteger appoved = [[approve valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"] intValue];
        NavWeekScreen.ApprovalorNot = appoved;
        NSInteger sumArray = [[totalhours valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"] floatValue];
        NavWeekScreen.totalhrsAdd = sumArray;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please don't upload your entire program to SO. You should debug your code and find the relevant methods causing the issue rather than relying on the community to read through everything you have written to solve your problem

Comment: @DanielGalasko Actually I worked on this for couple of days and was unable to find the exact issue. it would be better if we can share the entire code so that the person who responds will know me where I was going wrong.

Comment: But that's exactly it, you haven't showed us exactly what you have tried that's why it looks like you haven't tried anything:) I'm still unclear on your issue, is your table not showing any data?

Comment: Yes My table is not showing my data.. I am sorry this will not be repeated for the next time I post.. :)

Comment: It use to be working fine When I run this application in IOS 6 and IOS 7, recently I upgraded my MAC to IOS 8 from there I was having few issues.

Comment: Are the cellForRow methods being called? Have you tried providing a constant value in the height for Roe method?

Comment: I guess I did not try that for cellForRowAtIndexPath, May I know-how we can do that?

Comment: Place a breakpoint inside cellForRow? If it gets hit then try the next step

Comment: Yes when I place a break point it is hitting the break point, But there are few conditions there, so I guess it is moving into the wrong condition